# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la hora y la fecha más reciente de una agrupacion de datos?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL

```
select 
distinct p.USUARIO_GRUPAL ,p.HORA 
from TELE_MSJ p 
where p.HORA=(select max(p2.HORA) from TELE_MSJ p2);
```

Donde la columna `s.USUARIO_GRUPAL` Muestra una serie de usuarios que se repiten debido a la existencia de nuevos registros, anteriormente tenia dos columnas una de FECHA y la otra de HORA, y se almacenaban por aparte, se modifico y ahora solo se almacenan en la columna `HORA` se le asigno el tipo de dato TIMESTAMP, y me guarda fechas con este formato `26/08/22 13:02:20.040000000`, requiero que no se repitan los usuarios y me muestre la fecha mas reciente ingresada de cada usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon tanto la consulta como las salidas _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask].

Comment: Tenes que unir fecha y hora en un solo campo, y ahi aplicar el max, agrupando por el usuario... de paso, una de las tablas no parece tener nada qeu ver aca, no?

Comment: Que tal @gbianchi intente eso y solo me muestra un unsuario y es el que tiene la fecha mas reciente pero no los otros esta es mi consulta `select distinct p.USUARIO_GRUPAL ,p.HORA from TELE_MSJ p where p.HORA=(select max(p2.HORA) from TELE_MSJ p2);` espero me puedas ayudar un saludo.

Comment: Listo.. ahora es un simple group by... lo intentaste con group by?

Comment: @gbianchi Así es hice algo así `select p.USUARIO_GRUPAL ,p.HORA from TELE_MSJ p group by p.USUARIO_GRUPAL; ` y me manda error dice que no es una expresión GROUP BY

Comment: claro.. vos que queres de la fecha? el maximo, no? entonces, deberias usar una de las funciones de agrupacion para decirle que poner en cada grupo... o sea.. un max.. te recomendaria buscar como funciona group by.. y leerlo todo...

Comment: Si esque tengo `select p.USUARIO_GRUPAL ,p.HORA,p.MENSAJE from TELE_MSJ p group by p.USUARIO_GRUPAL;` hay una columna que guardara un mensaje que es `p.MENSAJE` entonces para ello requiero obtener los usuarios con las fechas mas recientes en la columna p.HORA , para extraer el mensaje que tiene ese usuario.

Comment: Y esa es otra pregunta, que no esta en tu pregunta.. no? Entonces o es un group by con un subquery, o es usando la clausula over... pero fijate... ahora volviste a cambiar la pregunta... y eso que pones no esta ahi arriba...

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Por lo que veo esta mal diseñada tu BD, tienes separada la hora y fecha en columnas diferentes, te recomiendo que uses el tipo [DATETIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) de SQL así puedes usar un ORDER BY "columna con fecha" DESC.

No sé bien que motor de base de datos uses, pero en caso de que por algún motivo no tenga DATETIME, puedes guardar la fecha en [Unix Timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)
y hacer un ORDER BY, solo que te va a tocar convertir de Unix TimeStamp a DateTime.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola que tal @Martín Cruz use DATETIME y me coloca ambos fecha y hora en una misma columna  y borre mi columna que contenia la fecha, lo hice de esta forma. solo que aun no puedo ver la fecha mas reciente de cada usuario. esta es mi consulta `select distinct (p.USUARIO_GRUPAL),p.HORA from TELE_MSJ p where p.HORA=(select max(p1.HORA) from TELE_MSJ p1);` Me muestra solo el usuario con la fecha mas reciente agregada

Comment: @HipolitoMatiasMiguelAngel si arreglaste la base de datos, entonces edita tu pregunta, agrega esa nueva informacion.. Estas haciendo mal tu query, se hace con group by.. no con distinct... si no, por supuesto va a devolver un solo registro...

Comment: @gbianchi listo se modifico la pregunto.